# Mongodb combine lookup and update

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Is it possible update a database, based on a lookup value?

```
pipeline = [
{'$limit': 10000}, # to limit query for testing purpose
{'$lookup':  # left join of user_cities DB
     {'from': 'weather_mapping',
      'localField': 'cityId',
      'foreignField': 'id',
      'as': 'mapping'}
 },
{'$lookup':  # left join of user_cities DB
     {'from': 'weather',
      'localField': 'mapping.okato',
      'foreignField': 'okato',
      'as': 'weahter'}
 }, ]
{'$out': 'activity_weather'}  #HERE I WOULD LIKE TO UPDATE THE ORIGINAL DOCUMENT RATHER THAN GENERATING A NEW ONE
db['activity'].aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Is it possible to include an update command rather than '$out' or vice versa put a $lookup inside the update command?

Comment: No it is not possible. You can loop the output cursor and issue updates, and preferably with the bulk API but there is no operation that contains updates on the server. Also since `$lookup` is getting data from another collection, there is also no possible way to write to more than one collection with a single operation. Even bulk API operations work with one collection only.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks! Even though not what I hoped for, this was a very clear answer.